# Add button to backend that runs a script

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, backend

I would like to add a button to the backend that runs a script. Preferably on the Index Management page under the existing indexing table. Is this a simple procedure?

I have the script and its working I just want the admin users to be able to run it from the backend. I don't want to run it from the browser as it will most probably time out.

Comment: if you will run it with backend button then also you will face same issue of time out

Comment: Right, if the script is prone to timeout it does not matter whether you run it from a frontend or backend controller or as an external script. As long as you call it from a browser same limitations will apply on all of them. You should consider setting up a scheduled task within Magento's cron handling.